# How can I get Google to index Blogger posts with over 200 comments?

Tags: seo, blogger, blogspot

In Blogger(Blogspot), Google doesn't index blog comments if it goes over 200 comments. Does anyone know how to make search engines index blog post that have more than 200 comments?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Blogger blogs are set with comments no-follow, no matter how many there are.

Comment: The problem is if comments < 200, Google still index it, but Google  doesn't index comments from number 201